# Having trouble adding new strings to an existing text file

Tags: python, python-3.8

I am messing around with some code to learn how to use the write and read method. So far I opened up a file called output.txt and stripped the whole line and also the last character of the line. Then I lower case all the characters that are in the output.txt. I am having trouble adding the content from variable lc to output.txt without deleting what is already in the output.txt. I tried `f.write(lc)`  , but got an error (*io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable*)

Here is the code that I have so far

```
# open file using "with"
with open("output.txt",'w') as f:
    lines = f.read()
    
    # strip the newline and the last character from what is read in
    newLine = lines.strip()
    lastChar = lines.strip()[len(lines) - 1]

    # convert the text to lower case
    lc = newLine.lower()

    # print the lower-case text and a newline to standard output
    f.write(lc)
```

Comment: Do you understand what the `"w"` argument to `open` means?  Do you know what the alternatives to it are?

Comment: You can't read from a file when you open it in `w` mode.

Comment: Also `w` mode empties the file, so there's nothing to read.

Comment: `open(..., 'r+')`

Comment: to read and write in the sime time you have to use 'r+' mode

Comment: Please repeat your tutorial materials on file handling.  Pay special attention to the f`open` modes and their uses.

Comment: Thank you so much. I do understand what ```w``` and ```r``` do when using it. I did not know that ```r+``` was another alternatives. Thank you all, once again!

Answer (score 0):

you can't read from file using w mode , with'r+' mode, using write method will write the string object to the file based on where the pointer is.

```
# open file using "with"
with open("output.txt",'r+') as f:
    lines = f.read()
    
    # strip the newline and the last character from what is read in
    newLine = lines.strip()
    lastChar = lines.strip()[len(lines) - 1]

    # convert the text to lower case
    lc = newLine.lower()

    # print the lower-case text and a newline to standard output
    f.write(lc)
```